# Incremented by a value x but it gets incremented by value x-1

Tags: java, if-statement, increment

I am implementing an Algorithm where when user gives input string, every character in string (if it is alphabet) should be incremented by value given(here rotator). I am playing with this code for 2 hr but can't figure out why when i increment by value rotator, it gets incremented by rotator-1.

```
public class Solution {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT. Your class should be named Solution. */
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int length = in.nextInt();
    String input = in.next();
    int nextvalue = 0;
    int temp = 0;
    char array[] = input.toCharArray();
    int rotator =  in.nextInt();
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        if((array[i] >= 'a' && array[i] <= 'z') || (array[i] >= 'A' && array[i] <= 'Z')){
            nextvalue = (int)array[i] + rotator;
            array[i] = (char)nextvalue;

            if((int)array[i] > (int)'z'){
                temp = (int)array[i] - (int)'z';
                nextvalue = (int)'a' + temp -1;
                array[i] = (char)nextvalue;
             }
            else if((int)array[i] > (int)'Z'){
                temp = (int)array[i] - (int)'Z';
                nextvalue = (int)'Z' + temp -1;
                array[i] = (char)nextvalue;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(array);
    }
}
```

Inside first if there are two if statements to handle(Overflow condition) if letter is > z or >Z. Now if I Remove those two statements everything except overflow condition is correctly printed

**(without overflow condition)
Sample I/P :**

11   <- String length

middle-Outz

2   <- rotator

**Sample O/P :**

okffng-Qwv`|`   <- Overflow condition not handled

**(with overflow condition)
Sample I/P :**

11

middle-Outz

2

**Sample O/P :**

njeemf-Qvu`b` <- Overflow handled but everything else incremented by rotator - 1 except 'Q'

Why is this happening? I also checked using print statement in **inner if condition , it executes only one time for this input since there is only one overflow condition**.

Help/Suggestion appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: `char array[]` is incorrect syntax. Did you mean `char[] array`?

Comment: downvoter please comment !

Comment: @Gooz Actually, I think it is legitimate syntax, though perhaps not what you find being promoted on the Oracle official site.

Comment: @Gooz both are valid in java

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, oh really, I genuinely didn't know about that.

Comment: @Gooz Yeah, neither did I...I actually learned on Stack Overflow :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the easiest way to handle the overflow cases is to use the modulus operator to let the character wrap-around any number of times to land in the current logical position.  Something like this should work:

```
for (int i=0; i < length; i++) {
    if (array[i] >= 'a' && array[i] <= 'z') {
        int currDiff = (int)array[i] - (int)'a';
        int newPos = (int)'a' + ((rotator + currDiff) % 26);
        array[i] = (char)newPos;
    }
    else if (array[i] >= 'A' && array[i] <= 'Z') {
        int currDiff = (int)array[i] - (int)'A';
        int newPos = (int)'A' + ((rotator + currDiff) % 26);
        array[i] = (char)newPos;
    }
}
```

I tested this code using an input string of `abcdefg` and a `rotator` value of 51, which returned `zabcdef`.  This is expected, because we rotated one step short of two complete rounds.  Hence, the `a` landed on `z`, after one complete rotation, and the following characters followed suit.

Note that there is a much nicer way of handling the calculus of character positions here, but this answer stays true to the way you were doing it in your original question.

**Final note:**

The modulus operator `%` returns the *remainder* of the division of the number which *preceeds* it and *proceeds* it.  In the solution I gave above, I take the effective rotator % 26.  Here, the effective rotator is the current distance of the letter from either `a` or `A` *plus* however many steps we want to rotate.  By taking this number mod 26, we always will end up with a number between 0 and 25.  Hence, we will always take between 0 and 25 steps from `a` or `A`, which is the behavior you want in your program.

Comment: @minigeek Had a bug in there, try again

Comment: it was giving some wrong op before let me check again your edit

Comment: did it. Can you add little explaination how did that % thing work

Answer (score 2):

The mistake is in this line:

```
if ((int) array[i] > (int) 'Z') {
```

You have to keep in mind that lowercase letters come "after" uppercase letters: 'Z' is represented by 90, and (for example) 'j ' is represented by 106 (for more info see [this](http://www.asciitable.com/)). The reason why 'Q' isn't affected by this mistake is because it is also a capital letter, and thus has a smaller decimal representation than 'Z'.

To fix this, you have to replace the line of code above with something along the lines of this:

```
if ((int) array[i] > (int) 'Z' && (int) array[i] <= (int) 'Z' + rotator) {
```

Comment: Z is 90 in ascii !! A is 65 http://sticksandstones.kstrom.com/appen.html

Comment: @minigeek Sorry! A little mistake, fixed now.

Comment: oh yeah i did that mistake as well thanx

Answer (score 2):

Because you are modifying it twice in your loop.

```
for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
    if((array[i] >= 'a' && array[i] <= 'z') || (array[i] >= 'A' && array[i] <= 'Z')){
        nextvalue = (int)array[i] + rotator;
        array[i] = (char)nextvalue; //<-- modifies from m to o

        if((int)array[i] > (int)'z'){
            temp = (int)array[i] - (int)'z';
            nextvalue = (int)'a' + temp -1;
            array[i] = (char)nextvalue;
         }
        else if((int)array[i] > (int)'Z'){
            temp = (int)array[i] - (int)'Z';
            nextvalue = (int)'Z' + temp -1;
            array[i] = (char)nextvalue; //<--modifies again from o to n
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: that is in the if condition but. Only if overflow occurs, that should be changed , M i wrong?

Comment: It will always overflow when your first input (11) is greater than the number of chars in your string. Why aren't you just using the length of the char array? Then you wouldn't have any overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
nextvalue = (int)'Z' + temp -1;
```

Shouldn't it be

```
nextvalue = (int)'A' + temp -1;
```